# How to create a mouse following element, delayed and direction based?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

I am looking for a solution to let an image trace the mouse cursor direction based.

Based on https://codepen.io/redspiderfish/pen/MYmeYz I worked on this code: https://jsfiddle.net/h78wm1nz/

Trying to add the rotation with the following code based on http://jsfiddle.net/dPDF3. But bee looks drunk.

```
 var img = $('#wunderbiene img');
//if (img.length > 0) {
var offset = img.offset();

function beeMouse(evt) {
  var center_x = (offset.left) + (img.width() / 2);
  var center_y = (offset.top) + (img.height() / 2);
  var mouse_x = evt.pageX;
  var mouse_y = evt.pageY;
  var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
  var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 180;
  img.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
  img.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
  img.css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
  img.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
}

//}



$(window).mouseenter(function() {
  $(document).mousemove(beeMouse);
}).mouseleave(function() {
  $(document).unbind();
});
```

Comment: Please, read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It is 1999 again!

Comment: So you listen for mousemove, record positions, and move your image to where you want.

Answer (score 3):

It is pretty much like @epascarello mentioned in the comments!

> So you listen for mousemove, record positions, and move your image to
>   where you want.

```js
var bee = document.getElementById("bee");
document.addEventListener("mousemove", getMouse);


bee.style.position = "absolute"; //css  
var beepos = {
 x: 0,
 y: 0
};

setInterval(followMouse, 75);

var mouse = {
 x: 0,
 y: 0
}; //mouse.x, mouse.y

var dir = "right";

function getMouse(e) {
 mouse.x = e.pageX;
 mouse.y = e.pageY;
 //Checking directional change
 if (mouse.x > beepos.x) {
  dir = "right";
 } else {
  dir = "left";
 }
}

function followMouse() {
 //1. find distance X , distance Y
 var distX = mouse.x - beepos.x;
 var distY = mouse.y - beepos.y;
 //Easing motion
 //Progressive reduction of distance 
 beepos.x += distX / 5;
 beepos.y += distY / 2;

 bee.style.left = beepos.x + "px";
 bee.style.top = beepos.y + "px";


 //Apply css class 
 if (dir == "right") {
  bee.setAttribute("class", "right");
 } else {
  bee.setAttribute("class", "left");
 }

}
```

```css
body {
 background-color: white;
}

.left {
 -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
 -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
 -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
 transform: scaleX(-1);
 filter: FlipH;
 -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}

.right {
 -moz-transform: scaleX(1);
 -o-transform: scaleX(1);
 -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
 transform: scaleX(1);
 filter: FlipH;
 -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}

#bee {
 transition: transform .1s
}

.trail {
 width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!--Image from: http://pngimg.com/uploads/bee/bee_PNG74646.png-->
<div id="bee"> 
   <img class="trail" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKDai.png"   />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. This is what I am working on. But I want the bee to "look" in the mouse direction. Please see my updated original post. This is my status quo https://jsfiddle.net/h78wm1nz/

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. Thanks for the help guys.

```js
        // BASED ON https://codepen.io/redspiderfish/pen/MYmeYz
        var bee = document.getElementById("wunderbiene");
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", getMouse);


        bee.style.position = "absolute"; //css
        var beepos = { x: 0, y: 0 };

        setInterval(followMouse, 25);

        var mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 }; //mouse.x, mouse.y

        var dir = "right";
        function getMouse(e) {
            mouse.x = e.pageX;
            mouse.y = e.pageY;
            //Checking directional change
            if (mouse.x > beepos.x) {
                //dir = "right";
            } else {
                //dir = "left";
            }

            // Adding Rotation based on http://jsfiddle.net/dPDF3
            var img = $('#wunderbiene img');
            if (img.length > 0) {
                var offset = img.offset();
                //function beeMouse(evt) {
                var center_x = (offset.left) + (img.width() / 2);
                var center_y = (offset.top) + (img.height() / 2);
                var mouse_x = e.pageX; var mouse_y = e.pageY;
                var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
                var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 180;
                img.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
                img.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
                img.css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
                img.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
                //}

            }


        }

        function followMouse() {
            //1. find distance X , distance Y
            var distX = mouse.x - beepos.x;
            var distY = mouse.y - beepos.y;
            //Easing motion
            //Progressive reduction of distance 
            beepos.x += distX / 40;
            beepos.y += distY / 40;

            bee.style.left = beepos.x + "px";
            bee.style.top = beepos.y + "px";


            //Apply css class 
            if (dir == "right") {
                bee.setAttribute("class", "right");
            } else {
                bee.setAttribute("class", "left");
            }

        }
```

```css
        body {
            background-color: #000;
            min-height: 300vh
        }

        .left {
            -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
            -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
            -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
            transform: scaleX(-1);
            filter: FlipH;
            -ms-filter: "FlipH";
        }

        .right {
            -moz-transform: scaleX(1);
            -o-transform: scaleX(1);
            -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
            transform: scaleX(1);
            filter: FlipH;
            -ms-filter: "FlipH";
        }

        #wunderbiene {
            transition: transform .15s
        }

        #wunderbiene img {
            width: 73px;
            position: relative;
            left:-50%;
            top: 50px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wunderbiene">
        <img id="wunimg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/91/Abeille-bee.svg" />
    </div>
```